# Is it true that 'for' in the 'for-to construction' has no identifiable meaning of its own?

Tags: infinitive-constructions, for-to-complementizers

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 1183) has this:

> *For* must occupy initial position in the subordinate clause. We have noted that it can’t occur in the interrogative and *wh* relative constructions [22]: this is because the initial position is there pre-empted by the interrogative subordinator *whether* and the interrogative and relative phrases. Its syntactic role is therefore closely parallel to that of the finite clause subordinator *that*, which is likewise excluded from interrogative and *wh* relative constructions. **Like *that*, *for* has no identifiable meaning of its own, but serves as a syntactic marker of a particular syntactic construction.** The functional similarity to *that* is particularly clear in such pairs as the following, where we find a direct contrast between finite and infinitival clauses: 
> [41] i a. *It is important t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲d̲e̲t̲a̲i̲l̲e̲d̲ ̲r̲e̲c̲o̲r̲d̲s̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲k̲e̲p̲t̲*. 
> b. *It is important f̲o̲r̲ ̲d̲e̲t̲a̲i̲l̲e̲d̲ ̲r̲e̲c̲o̲r̲d̲s̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲k̲e̲p̲t̲*.
> ii a. *That’s the best course t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲ ̲c̲a̲n̲ ̲t̲a̲k̲e̲*. 
> b. *That’s the best course f̲o̲r̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲t̲a̲k̲e̲*. 
> iii a. *I̲n̲ ̲o̲r̲d̲e̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲i̲l̲l̲ ̲m̲a̲y̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲p̲a̲s̲s̲e̲d̲ major amendments were made*. 
> b. *I̲n̲ ̲o̲r̲d̲e̲r̲ ̲f̲o̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲i̲l̲l̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲p̲a̲s̲s̲e̲d̲ major amendments were made*.

(Boldface mine.)

But there seem to be cases where *for* does have an identifiable meaning of its own, as in (1):

> (1) *He called f̲o̲r̲ ̲c̲l̲o̲s̲e̲ ̲t̲a̲b̲s̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲k̲e̲p̲t̲ ̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲n̲e̲w̲ ̲r̲e̲c̲r̲u̲i̲t̲s̲.*

This example is from CGEL on the same page.

Here, *for* seems to have its own meaning to assist the meaning of the verb *called*. If so, does the above statement in bold apply to only some 'for-to constructions' as in [41]?

### EDIT

(1) could have been an answer to this question:

> *What did he call for?*

So it's unlikely that *for* in (2) is bleached of its original meaning in the question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151934/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-is-it-true-that-for-in-the-for-to-construction); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

1. She called for a ceasefire.
2. She called for a ceasefire to be negotiated.

The preposition *for* in (1) would be recognised by most grammarians as a meaningful preposition, one selected by the verb *call*. It's taking an NP (noun phrase) complement, *a ceasefire*.

According to CamGEL, the word *for* in (2) is a completely different word, an absolutely meaningless subordinator which introduces infinitival clauses whenever they have subjects— a bit like the word *that* in *I think (that) you rock*.

However, the verb *call* does not have a *call for* meaning (where the *for* has the meaning it does in '*call for a ceasefire*') when it appears all on its own. In *'She called a pigeon'*, the verb *call* does not mean *call for*.

The parallelism between (1) and (2) is one type of reason amongst many that well-respected modern grammarians like Bas Aarts (of *Oxford Modern English Grammar*, *English Syntax and Argumentation* and Director of the Survey of English Usage at UCL) argue that *for* in environments like (2) and in OP's example, is a preposition, not a subordinator (and in fact that it may *always* be a preposition).

Bas Aarts' arguments (which are cast syntactically rather than semantically) can be found in the following paper. You'll need to register for free to download it. But it's well worth registering. Tonnes of interesting papers to download!

> [Bas Aarts: What For?](https://www.academia.edu/38174264/What_for_pre_publication_pdf)

Here is Aarts's abstract for the chapter:

> The lexical item for is historically a preposition, though in Present-Day English it is also often categorized as a subordinator/complementizer in so-called for…to constructions (Rosenbaum 1967, Bresnan 1972). In this paper I will begin by offering an overview of the syntactic structures in which for appears. I will then focus on the analysis of for as a complementizer in for…to constructions which has become commonplace, and has rarely been questioned. First I will discuss the arguments that have been put forward to support this analysis critically, and will then argue instead that for is in fact always a preposition. I will offer an analysis which can account for constructions in which for licenses an NP, a finite clause, a to-infinitive clause, or an -ing-clause. This will result in simplified lexical entries for many verbs that license complements involving for.

Comment: Actually, you led me to the paper a couple years ago, so I am well aware of its approach. But Aarts didn't list _for_ having a meaning as one of the reasons why it's a preposition. Are you aware of modern grammarians who treat _for_ in [_for_ NP _to_ VP] as a preposition because it has a meaning? // This may be a separate question but, frankly, I don't find Aarts's approach convincing. One problem is that, if _for_ is a preposition taking a clausal complement, [_for_ [NP _to_ VP]] would be not a clause but a PP, whereas, if it's a subordinator,  [_for_ [NP _to_ VP]] would be a clause.

Comment: @JK2 You're right so I've tightened up that paragraph. But while it's true that Aarts only mentions semantics overtly in a couple of places, many of the arguments ride on the semantics. The reason Aarts does not state that overtly is because it does not further his argument that *for* is *always* a preposition - because clearly there are cases where infinitival *for* does **not** have any semantic content. Mentioning the semantic argument overtlywould actually weaken the larger claim. But if you look at the arguments, for example, on p.69 relating to (60-70), they basically have a semantic ...

Comment: @JK2 basis. Same is true for the "double-barrelled" constructions, for example, discussed on p.59 and elsewhere. Bas writes: *Some constructions are what Jespersen calls ‘double-barrelled’, i.e. ambiguous between a reading in which* for *belongs to the higher clause and one in which it belongs to the lower clause, as in (26).* There the word *ambiguous clearly means *semantically* ambiguous. But, in general, the idea that *for* has semantic content is unhelpful for because, exactly as you suggest above, it needs to be uniformly semantically contentful or empty to be useful to either camp.

Comment: Here's a question I've posted on Linguistics. You might be the best person to give an answer: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/48484/3380